# Remove top level QMenu from QMenubar programmatically

Tags: python, pyqt, qmenu

I am working on a Python project that uses Qt Designer to build interface. when working on building a plugin capability, I was able to allow dynamic loading of user plugins and create a new `QMenu` item to add to the main menubar. The problem is that there seems to be no way of removing that top level `QMenu` once it is added to the main menubar. I researched/searched quite a bit on this topic and it seems that every solution related to this topic is for removing sub-menu items from a `QMenu` via removing its actions, *not* for removing that dynamically-added `QMenu` itself. I hope someone would point out this to be a simple thing, and provide a code snippet to demo how this is done.

Comment: Are you using QMainWindow ?

Comment: yes, my form is sub to QMainWindow

Comment: self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Dialog) &         self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal) don't do what you looking for ?

Comment: I am not sure about the relevance of your suggestion to my original problem that is to remove a dynamically added QMenu on the main menu bar of a QMainwindow form

Comment: Oh sorry I read wrong, I thought you want to remove QMenuBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will give you idea for what you upto. And I took some part from another post, which is same qmenu thing

```
import sys
# This is bad, but Iam lazy 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.main_menu = self.menuBar()
        widget = QWidget()
        self.menuList = []
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.menuButton = QPushButton("Add Menu")
        self.menuRmButton = QPushButton("Remove Menu")
        layout2.addWidget(self.menuButton)
        layout2.addWidget(self.menuRmButton)
        self.menuButton.clicked.connect(self.create_menu)
        self.menuRmButton.clicked.connect(self.removeMenu)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def create_menu(self):
        menu2 = self.main_menu.addMenu('Menu 1')
        self.menuList.append(menu2)
        Action1=QAction('Menu 1 0',self)
        Action1.triggered.connect(self.action_1)
        menu2.addAction(Action1)

        Action2=QAction('Menu 1 1',self)
        Action2.triggered.connect(self.action_2)
        menu2.addAction(Action2)

    def removeMenu(self):
        if self.menuList:
            for eachMenu in self.menuList:
                menuAct = eachMenu.menuAction()
                self.main_menu.removeAction(menuAct)
                # just for safe side
                menuAct.deleteLater()
                eachMenu.deleteLater()

    def action_1(self):
        print('Menu 1 0')

    def action_2(self):
        print('Menu 1 1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    new=MyWindow()
    new.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Achayan, this worked. I think I tried this approach myself by attaching an action to the top level QMenu, but perhaps my syntax was not quite right. Especially the Action1 = QAction('', self) statement and the use of self as the 2nd argument. I think to get rid of the "additional" fake sub-menu item (i.e. 'Menu 1 0'), one need to set Action1 to invisible like Action1.setVisible(False)

Answer (score 2):

Achayan's solution above crashes on python2 qt4 (Windows) for the deletion

Better way for it is to to use the clear function.

Adding to the solution above,

```
def removeMenu():
    self.main_menu.clear()
```

Comment: That's the right way, thanks! https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html